# Why does CPUUtilization Alarm have always INSUFFICIENT_DATA state?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, scaling, amazon-cloudwatch, autoscaling

I'm trying to create an **Auto-Scaling Group**, which will work based upon **CPUUtilization** of the Target Group.

I managed to created an Auto-Scaling group. When I execute the Scaling Policies via some test data. It works.

I created 2 alarms in Cloudwatch. However, those are in "**INSUFFICIENT_DATA**".

The alarms should be able to checking the CPUUtilization of the Auto-Scaling Group.

**So, how can I run the autoscaling based on CPUUtilization of Target Group?**

The screentshots are below:

[The loadbalancer configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TkzUd.png)

[The target group configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K25EF.png)

[The autoscaling configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nBLWV.png)

[The scaling policies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O1igY.png)

[The CloudWatch alarm config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PDPxc.png)

[Alarm configuration for Scale-UP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8HUDP.png)

[Alarm configuration for Scale-Down](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zk4Fh.png)

Comment: Do you have any other working alarm?

Comment: I have only 2 alarms.

Comment: Do you have Windows machines in your ASG?

Comment: nope. i don't have windows.

Answer (score 0):

https://serverfault.com/questions/479689/cloudwatch-alarms-strange-behavior

I found this answer. My alarm works for period 1 minute. But my cloudwatch monitoring wasn't detailed.

When I change the alarm checking period from 1 minute to 1 hour, the alarm works. However, I need to execute the alarm for period 1 minute. I enabled the detailed monitoring but still doesn't work.